# (tutoring) tag proposal

Tags: discussion, tagging, proposal

It was requested that I introduce a separate question/proposal so that members of the community could discuss the practicality of a tag such as (tutoring) . I propose a (tutoring) tag that would indicate a more *specific* type of approach towards responding to a question.

~Thank you

Comment: Mmmm... meta-tags.

Comment: @Asaf:  Well, we already have 'homework', right?  But yeah, I do rather doubt this proposal will be acceptable, though I wish that were not the case.

Comment: @Tara: And we have [tag:big-list], [tag:soft-question] and [tag:reference-request] too. But meta tags are generally bad.

Comment: Can you provide some some of idea of what "more _specific_ type of approach towards responding to a question" would be indicated by the inclusion of this proposed tag?

Comment: @Asaf:  Hmm, I don't really think of reference-request as a meta-tag.

Comment: @Tara: And whose fault is this? :-) But more seriously, the reference request tag is a meta-tag because it indicates that the OP is looking for a reference, it does not indicate what is the topic of the actual reference.

Comment: @AsafKaragila:  Right, I see.

Comment: [The "meta-tags"](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/2498/the-meta-tags) in [faq](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq)

Comment: @ArthurFischer Any sort of response that elicits, or attempts to elicit the higher faculties of thought from the questioner's part, about their question. Open-ended questions, wisdom about the particular question or subject at hand, hints, or even partial answers are some suggestions. Use your imagination.

Comment: @Arthur: You give quite a few answers that I think would qualify; [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/325750/12042) is one, for instance.

Comment: I'm pretty agnostic about this proposal so far, but I do strongly feel that a meta-tag such as this should be well-defined before being added.  I still don't feel that it has been carved out enough for me to vote one way or the other.  (As an aside, I'll take whatever compliments I receive from @Brian as praise from Caesar himself!)

Comment: @Arthur: Did you just call Brian a crazy megalomaniac who will soon take over this republic and become its emperor?

Comment: @Asaf: Trust me, I’m not [Norton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emperor_Norton) II!

Comment: @Brian: Hah! That's a lovely slice of history. I was more worried that you'll go Nero, rather than going Norton though. :-)

Answer (score 5):

I think there will probably be a lot of objection to this idea, because this is apparently supposed to be a question-and-answer site rather than a tutoring site.  But the fact is that it *can* be and *is* used for something more in the style of tutoring, and this is something I would like to see a lot more of, because I only participate here in the hope of helping people (and very occasionally getting some help myself) and it saddens me that so much of what goes on here is probably very far from helpful to the people asking questions.

I strongly support the idea of such a tag (I'm not quite sure what the best name for it is - 'tutoring' could sound a little as if it might be for questions about how to tutor maths, and it seems we can't expect people to read the tag wiki).

How I envision it working is that it would be used by people who specifically want to be guided towards a solution rather than having it handed to them all in one go.  Ideally we would be able to somehow make it very clear that it is unacceptable to simply provide an answer to a question with this tag.  It would also be nice for the sake of those who care about reputation$^*$ if people would vote on answers to questions with this tag based on the entire interaction rather than just the body of the initial answer.
Answering a question in more of a 'tutoring' style can take more thought and time-commitment than even a long 'straight answer', so I suppose it'd be nice to have this sort of interaction appreciated more.
This style of answering my also result in a final answer by the OP, and it'd be nice for this to receive some upvotes as well if it's correct, even if it may not be as well-written as most answers on this site.

This is far from a perfect solution to the "curtailing of students' potential" Rustyn has [expressed concern](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8703/curtailing-a-students-potential) about, since this tag would be used completely voluntarily by the asker.  But it would at least help us not to rob a student of the greater learning opportunity of coming to the answer partially by themselves when they specifically don't *want* this to happen.

$^*$(I don't, although I do somewhat mind unexplained downvotes.)

Comment: I like this in principle, though i think it would be difficult to make work on a large scale given the design of the site. The comment space makes it difficult for multiple threads of conversation to go on simultaneously (seemingly by design), for one. I have no experience with chat (the interface seems quite cumbersome), But that may be one outlet. It also requires a certain disposition on the part of the person seeking help. That said, as an answerer, even now, on rare occasions [you get lucky](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/67287/7003).

Comment: @cardinal:  I'm definitely more concerned about it from the askers' perspective.  Fairly frequently full answers are given even when only a hint was asked for.

Comment: Dear @TaraB: Yes, I understand. My comment was intended from that perspective as well, even if, by the end, it didn't seem like it. :-)

Comment: @cardinal What's wrong with it beginning as a small dialogue in the comments and then at some point, (if necessary), the: "let us continue this discussion in chat" option.

Comment: @cardinal: Once you install the MathJax bookmarklet, chat isn’t too bad, **provided** that only one discussion is taking place, with a severely limited number of participants, and the site architecture does support private rooms.

Comment: @Rustyn:  The main problem with this is the current reputation requirement for chatting.

Comment: Hi @Brian: Thanks. Yes, I have robjohn's very nifty bookmarklet. I've entered the chat a few times on purpose and probably more times on accident. I think navigating through it could be more intuitive, though it's relatively painless via the "let us continue this discussion in chat" link. I wholeheartedly agree that it would be hard to manage several people simultaneously trying to engage the OP in this manner through comments or chat. That was one aspect of what I was attempting to express in my first comment. :-)

Comment: @Brian: And, I should probably be a little more adventurous. :-)

Comment: @cardinal: I know it from experience in the main MSE chat room: there’s nothing quite like trying to follow four separate conversations going on simultaneously, even with the feature that lets you link a post to the one to which you’re responding!

Comment: @cardinal Why is it that several people are engaging the OP and not just one? After all, this sort of thing isn't for reputation and it's not like there'd be community members slobbering over being the first one to tutor the OP.

Comment: @Rustyn: I’ve seen it happen when people ask a question in the main MSE chat room. There was also, for a while, a room set up for someone who was working through Just & Weese’s set theory text, and several of us were helping with the discussions there. That one worked reasonably well: we were all pretty good about not getting in one another’s way.

Comment: @TaraB I don't forsee a problem... Comments should be ample enough. I don't understand how anyone who actually _wants_ tutoring would need a massive dialogue.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Well as long as the slobbering tutors don't get in each other's way...

Comment: @Rustyn: It happens sometimes, if the OP has a blind spot. Or if the person answering the question has a blind spot: see [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/324846/12042) embarrassing chain of comments.

Comment: @Brian: You never visited big chatrooms in the early days of the internet, or IRC chats, have you?

Comment: @Asaf: Nope; this is the only place that I’ve used a chat facility. Though I’ve carried on some almost chat-like conversations on Usenet.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott,cardinal Tutoring won't always be perfect but it's a step in a new direction for the site. Every new beginning has an associated risk. We'll have to wait and see what the rest of everyone thinks. I'm sure someone with a lot of reputation is bound to come in and present an overwhelming argument for its infeasibility and wipe the floor with this anyhow. You've got to give me credit for trying though!

Comment: @Brian: "there’s nothing quite like trying to follow four separate conversations going on simultaneously" sort of gave it away. As someone who's been hanging out in many kinds of chatrooms ever since his first encounter with them 16 years ago, four conversations is challenging but far from difficult. :-)

Comment: @Asaf: I don’t actually have trouble with the casual conversations, but the mathematical ones tend to suffer a bit. And I suspect that my mother would have been driven nuts trying to deal even with the casual ones.

Comment: @Rustyn:  Well, some hope against that is the Brian and Asaf haven't really 'wiped the floor with this' yet, and they have some of the highest reputations around. =]

Comment: Wiped the floor with what?

Comment: @AsafKaragila the proposal

Comment: Except engaging with Brian in some off-topic chat, and pointing out that this is a proposal for yet another meta tag (which is generally frowned upon), I didn't even give my opinion about the actual proposal. Although I am currently not in favor of adding such meta tag, I have no good reason. That been said, I have learned to trust my guts when they tell me I'm hungry, or that a decision is bad.

Answer (score 4):

I see a basic problem with the proposed tag: *Who will add the [tutoring] tag to a question?* That is, how can we know if tutoring-style answers are desirable for a question? This seems difficult for anyone else to judge unless the asker explicitly says so. Already we have the situation that [it is deemed inappropriate for anyone but the asker to add the [homework] tag](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/8608/856), and it's likely that the same objections will be raised for [tutoring].

So it's not at all clear to me what benefit this tag will provide. For questions that clearly ask for hints and guidance, tagging it [tutoring] adds no information. For questions that are essentially pasted from an exercise and provide little further context, there will be debates and friction in the comments about whether or not the tag should be added; meanwhile both full answers and tutoring attempts will continue to be posted. Compared to what happens at present, the only difference is the addition of comment drama.

Comment: Certainly if such a tag were to be introduced, it should only ever be added by the asker.  I don't think this would be at all likely to cause as much 'comment drama' as with the homework tag.

Answer (score 2):

this is not useful as a tag, but it is a good idea that people ask for the type of help they want. In fact this already happens sometimes so no change is needed.

Comment: Unfortunately people are not always _given_ the type of help they ask for.  I've seen numerous examples of very detailed hints when all that was asked for was a hint to help with getting started.  Of course I don't believe just adding a new tag will fix that.